# Submit on enter with 2 text inputs

Tags: forms, submit

I have two text inputs and each has a submit button. Each button has an on click AJAX function that calls a php script and populates the page.

I need to find a way to make the enter key submit the button of the input text focused.

For example if I type something the in the "product_code" input text and press the Enter key I want to call the AJAX function of that input's assigned button (getByCode()).

```
Product name: <input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name">
<input type="submit" value="Search" onClick="searchByName(document.getElementById('product_name').value)"> <br />



Product code: <input type="text" name="product_code" id="product_code">
<input type="submit" value="Search" onClick="getByCode(document.getElementById('product_code').value)"> <br />
```

I don't necessarily require input buttons, I could use images for example if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All browsers support `document.activeElement` which will tell you which element has focus. On your keypress event handler, check this value against your two inputs to see which has focus. If neither has focus, then ... ?

Comment: Well, I found this `<textarea onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { this.form.submit(); return false; }"></textarea> `
I'm going to check it out and see how can I modify it

Comment: Did it with `onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { getByCode(document.getElementById('product_code').value); }"`
Thanks !